# Equivalent to refer to control by variable name?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, controls

In VB I can loop through controls, or refer to a control by concatenating a variable to a string.  Something like:

```
Dim I as integer
I = 1
Me["Textbox" & I].Text = "Some text"
```

What is the C# equivalent of this last statement?

Comment: are you sure this line `Me["Textbox" & I].Text = "Some text"` works in VBNet?

Comment: Not sure about VB.net, but defintely normal VB and VBA.  I assumed the behaviour will be carried over to VB.net

Comment: Why should he remove the C# tag? This is manifestly a question about how to do something in C#! Or he should at least add the WinForms tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the control by the control's name:

```
Me.Controls("TextBox" & I).Text = "Some text"
```

And the same in C#:

```
this.Controls["TextBox" + I].Text = "Some text";
```

Comment: C# does not have the Me collection.  And replacing Me with this does not work either.  No wait.  Using the controls collection might work...

Answer (score 2):

```
 int I = 1;
 this["Textbox" + I].Text = "some text";
```

OR

```
 int I = 1;
 this.Page["Textbox" + I].Text = "some text";
```

OR

```
 int I = 1;
 this.Controls["Textbox" + I].Text = "some text";
```

Comment: Seems like this is not working.  Need to specify the Controls collection.

Answer (score 2):

Close to SysDragan' solution, but Me just needs to be replaced with this.  And yes, you need to specify the Controls collection.

```
this.Controls["TextBox" & I].Text = "Some text";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = 1;
this.Controls["TextBox" & i].Text = "Some text";
```

The above code is assuming that it is in a Control/Form.

Comment: This does not give any compile errors, but in runtime it gives an error that the control is null.
In the immediate window it will say that this.Controls["MyControl1") have a value, but if I assign it to something the error is this.Controls["MyControl1"]' is null

Comment: Possible issues (1) a control named "TextBox1" is not defined (2) is not "IN" this control but a subcontrol (3) the control has been loaded yet.

Comment: 1. It is defined as I can read and the value from this.MyControl if I don't use the variable.  So I guess it is not in the Controls collection.  Will search some more.

Comment: Its most likely inside of a Panel or something.

Comment: Yes, it is a subcontrol.  It was on a tab control.  Thanks for help!!

Comment: Yes, you did.  But at the time of your answer it was still referring to Me instead of this.  It's now correct.