# Can you Create a textbox. Split it into a string and assign parameters to it. In vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I created a bowling program with lot of textboxs. I assign every textbox with a name like: `TextboxF1P1T1`, `TextboxF1P1T2`, `TextboxF1P2T1` etc.

```
Private Sub PlayFrame(frameNumber As Integer, player As Integer)

    'This works
    Dim throw1 As Integer
    Integer.TryParse(TextBoxF1P1T1.Text, throw1)
    'But i want something like this 
    Dim throw2 As Integer
    Integer.TryParse("TextBoxF" & frameNumber.ToString & "P" & player.ToString & "T2.Text", throw2)

    Dim frame As New Frame(1, throw1, throw2)
    frame.PlayTurn()
    LabelF1P1.Text = frame.TotaleScore.ToString

End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578957/equivalent-to-refer-to-control-by-variable-name

Comment: So adjust it to  `code Integer.TryParse(Me.Controls("TextBoxF" & frameNumber & "P" & player & "T2").Text, throw2) ` But i get  NullReferenceException @Fred

Comment: More than likely the Controls method is returning a Null Reference, because it can't find the control by the string. Before this line of code do Debug.WriteLine("TextBoxF" & frameNumber & "P" & player & "T2") to see if the resulting string is what you expect.

Comment: Yes that should work if `frameNumber`  and `player` hold numbers that make up the name of a control that actually exists.  I have tested it and it works fine.

Comment: @Jeremy if found the problem. I think its because the textbox is in a groupbox. Do you have a suggestion for this ?

Comment: See my answer below. The Find Method allows you to specify searching all sub collections, and should correctly return a reference to the textbox even if it belongs to a group.

Comment: @Jeremy Can't seem to figure this out. Can you give an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the control is in a `groupbox` reference it like this:

```
Dim throw2 As Integer
Integer.TryParse(GroupBox1.Controls("TextBoxF" & frameNumber.ToString & "P" & player.ToString & "T2").Text, throw2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Find method that belongs to the Controls collection.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx

Inside a form you can write

```
Me.Controls.Find(...)
```